# Connection from Spark to snowflake

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, databricks, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am writing this not for asking the question, but sharing the knowledge.
I was using Spark to connect to snowflake. But I could not access snowflake. It seemed like there was something wrong with internal JDBC driver in databricks.

Here was the error I got.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:net/snowflake/client/jdbc/internal/snowflake/common/core/S3FileEncryptionMaterial
```

I tried many versions of snowflake jdbc drivers and snowflake drivers. It seemed like I could match the correct one.

Comment: Your intention is much appreciated, But hence forth you could ask question with error message and other details. and in the answer section you could add your steps and code snippets. : Review

Comment: its [snowflake-datawarehouse] not snowflake schema modified tag

Answer (score 6):

Answer **as given by the asker** (I just extracted it from the question for better site usability:

Step 1: Create cluster with Spark version - 2.3.0. and Scala Version - 2.11

Step 2: Attached snowflake-jdbc-3.5.4.jar to the cluster.
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.snowflake/snowflake-jdbc/3.5.4

Step 3: Attached spark-snowflake_2.11-2.3.2 driver to the cluster. 
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.snowflake/spark-snowflake_2.11/2.3.2

Here is the sample code.

```
val SNOWFLAKE_SOURCE_NAME = "net.snowflake.spark.snowflake"

val sfOptions = Map(
    "sfURL" -> "<snowflake_url>",
    "sfAccount" -> "<your account name>",
    "sfUser" -> "<your account user>",
    "sfPassword" -> "<your account pwd>",
    "sfDatabase" -> "<your database name>",
    "sfSchema" -> "<your schema name>",
    "sfWarehouse" -> "<your warehouse name>",
    "sfRole" -> "<your account role>",
    "region_id"-> "<your region name, if you are out of us region>"
)

val df: DataFrame = sqlContext.read
    .format(SNOWFLAKE_SOURCE_NAME)
    .options(sfOptions)
    .option("dbtable", "<your table>")
    .load()
```

Answer (score 5):

If you are using Databricks, there is a [Databricks Snowflake connector](http://Databricks%20Snowflake%20connector) created jointly by Databricks and Snowflake people. You just have to provide a few items to create a Spark dataframe (see below -- copied from the Databricks document).

```
# snowflake connection options
options = dict(sfUrl="<URL for your Snowflake account>",
               sfUser=user,
               sfPassword=password,
               sfDatabase="<The database to use for the session after connecting>",
               sfSchema="<The schema to use for the session after connecting>",
               sfWarehouse="<The default virtual warehouse to use for the session after connecting>")

df = spark.read \
  .format("snowflake") \
  .options(**options) \
  .option("dbtable", "<The name of the table to be read>") \
  .load()

display(df)
```

As long as you are accessing your own databases with all the access rights granted correctly, this only take a few minutes, even during our first attempt.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the CLASSPATH Variables to point to jar like below. You need to set up SPARK_HOME and SCALA_HOME besides PYTHONPATH also.

---

export CLASSPATH=/snowflake-jdbc-3.8.0.jar:/spark-snowflake_2.11-2.4.14-spark_2.4.jar

---

You can also load in memory jars in your code to resolve this issue.

---

spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .config("spark.jars", "file:///app/snowflake-jdbc-3.9.1.jar,file:///app/spark-snowflake_2.11-2.5.3-spark_2.2.jar") \
    .config("spark.repl.local.jars",
            "file:///app/snowflake-jdbc-3.9.1.jar,file:///app/spark-snowflake_2.11-2.5.3-spark_2.2.jar") \
    .config("spark.sql.catalogImplementation", "in-memory") \
    .getOrCreate()

---

Answer (score -4):

Please update to the latest version of the Snowflake JDBC driver (3.2.5); that should resolve this issue. Thanks!